# Using ant.replace in gradle

Tags: replace, ant, gradle

I want to use ant's replace task to replace token in one of the files like this:

*version.txt*

```
version.number=${versionNumber}
```

*build.gradle*

```
task writeVersion {

   ant.replace {
      file 'version.txt'
      token 'versionNumber'
      value '1.0.0'
   }
}
```

but it is giving me following error :-

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project '1.01-Exercise-RunYourFirstTask'.
> replace doesn't support the nested "token" element.
```

Please , help me , how can I use ant's replace task to replace a token in a file or if there is any other function using which I can do it directly from gradle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
task writeVersion << {
    ant.replace(
      file: 'version.txt',
      token: 'versionNumber',
      value: '1.0.0'
 )
}
```

and:

```
version.number=versionNumber
```

Comment: What if I want to use a wildcard?  Like if I don't know whether **versionNumber** word is there, and I just want to replace it?